# Exception handling behaviour of code with two similar catch sections

Tags: c++

I have a short code that i created only for practice purposes, I wanted to check what is going to happen if I have two catch sections, one captures by reference (`int&`) and the second one catches by value (`int`). The problem is that when I run this code it appears that capture by reference occurs even though I threw "regular" integer. Why is this happening?

NOTE: When I compile this on MSVS17 I get error C2313:

> 'int': is caught by reference ('int&') on line 15

but when I use online compiler it works just fine.

When I remove one of the catch sections, it works just fine even in MSVS17, but still, why is catch section with reference invoked and not the other one

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    try {
        if (i)
            throw(i);
        return 0;
    }

    catch (int &)
    {
        cout << "Int&";
    }

    catch (int)
    {
        cout << "Int";
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the two `getchar()`s for?

Comment: @L.F.  nothing special, it's something i have in all my codes, if i press any button on keyboard accidentaly, it prevents window from closing immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

There is no priority in `catch`-matching. A `catch` either matches or it does not match. And reference is a match.

## Not-So-Short Answer

[cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch#Explanation):

> When an exception of type E is thrown by any statement in compound-statement, it is matched against the types of the formal parameters T of each catch-clause in handler-seq, in the order in which the catch clauses are listed.

i.e. The first match is selected (there is no concept "better" or "worse" match; a `catch` either matches or not.)

Further it says:

> The exception is a match if any of the following is true:
>
> - ...
> - T is an lvalue-reference to (possibly cv-qualified) E
> - ...

Therefore, `catch(int&)` is a match; `catch(int)` doesn't even have the opportunity to be considered.

## [Martin Bonner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771073/martin-bonner)'s example

Martin Bonner provides an excellent example to let you understand this, and the OP understands it thoroughly:

```
try {
    throw 5;
}
catch (int) { // int first
    // ...
}
catch (int&) { // this is not even considered!
    // ...
}
```

Comment: And likewise, if one wrote `try { throw 5; } catch (int) {... } catch (int&) {...}` it would be the `int` catch would be executed.

Comment: so basically if my first section of catch was the one with regular int, that would be the invoked section, and the one with reference would not be considered at all. Is that right?

Comment: I think the real point here is that exceptions are always thrown by value, thus both are an equally valid match. The other point is that, in the real world, you never have to worry about this, because you should always catch exceptions by reference---never by value.

Comment: @CodyGray -- it's not about **equally valid**; the **first valid** catch clause wins. There is no consideration of how good the match is. It's **not** like function overloading.